# Error in selenium when we execute multiple times

Tags: selenium

In Selenium first I record the some scenario and execute the test case, it works fine.

Next execution however results in an error message

> Element  not found

When I run the same test case, it is displaying the error message. Sometimes it is execution is working the same commands.

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: It may because of your site load too fast/too slow and it selenium some time not able to find element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple reasons for getting '*Element not found' error*. Some solutions:

**Reason 1**: If driver/script tries click/check the Web-element before it's loading then you might get the same message.
**Solution**: Try using **WaitAndClick**.

**Reason 2**: If the attribute used to locate Web-Element is Dynamic.

**Solution :** Try using other attribute if Web-Element which is unique and static.